# Remove item associative array by id (Javascript/Jquery)

Tags: jquery

I have an associative array and I would like to know how to remove items via the associative id.

```
MyArray[]

//Associative ID | value

term_1 > "string"
term_2 > "more string"
term_3 > "even more string!!"
```

I'm thinking something like...

```
var toRemove = "term_2";
$(myArray).splice(toRemove,1);
```

Comment: Associative arrays are poor practice. Use an object. Anyway it would be `delete myArray[toRemove]`

Comment: According to this article: http://www.laurencegellert.com/2012/01/associative-arrays-in-javascript/

associative arrays in javascript ARE objects.

Comment: According to me there are no real associative arrays in javascript, there's array and objects, and arrays are really objects, and objects are somewhat like associative arrays, so it's normal to be confused.